# Creating a 'sequence' of subsets using the subset axiom, then using induction to prove they are all equal

Tags: induction, set-theory, axioms

Setup:

$(N,\sigma)$ satisfies Peano axioms, i.e. $N \equiv  ω$.

Using the subset axiom we define, for each $k \in N$, $F_k = \{x \in N \; | \; \phi_k(x) \}$.

Next we define $D = \{d \in N \; | \; F_d = N\}$ and show that $1 \in D$ and when $d \in D$, so is $d + 1$ (using the fact that $F_d = N$). So $D = N$ and for all $k \in N$, $F_k = N$.

What axioms of ZF set theory come into play here?

The answer can be found by reading the comments, so I will list them here:

[Axiom_of_infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_infinity)

[Axiom of extensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality)

[Axiom schema of specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification)

---

I noticed that there is a vote to close this question - that it is unclear what I am asking. Well, without details, I guess it isn't the best question. But, the question did 'collect' three very important axioms from ZF set theory.

---

I thought that since induction isn't an axiom, it is nothing to make a 'fuss' about. But, it seems that I need to take a refresher course in induction. For example, have you used *simultaneous* induction lately?

For a review with exercises, see

[Induction](https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/system/files/attachments/induction_0.pdf)
by Richard Earl
Mathematical Institute, Oxford
August 2003

I am adding the induction tag to this posting.

Comment: How do the sets $F_k$ come to be different one of the other?

Comment: @AndréPorto Right - I changed the predicate - thanks!

Comment: The existence of $N$ is due to the axiom of infinity, but I guess there is one more axiom to conclude that there is a minimal inductive set. Then you fix $N$ to be a minimal inductive set that contains $\emptyset$. When you show that $\emptyset\in D$ and that $d\in D \Rightarrow d\cup\{d\}\in D$, you are showing that $D$ is an inductive set with $\emptyset \in D$ and contained in $N$, and since $N$ is minimal, it will follow that $D=N$.

Comment: You introduce a notation $\phi_k$ which you never define.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I didn't want to confuse the question with specifics - it is the mechanics that I found 'spooky'. The setup assumes the axiom of infinity - check. So two axioms. Others?

Comment: @AndréPorto My setup was an inductive set. So we need the axiom of infinity. Looks like the logic is correct, but I never did an induction like that (or at least one that I can remember).

Comment: This works perfectly ... **if** you can actually do it. Given a sequence of sets $A_k$ of natural numbers, you can indeed conclude $\forall k(A_k=\mathbb{N})$ if you have proved:

 - $A_0=\mathbb{N}$ and

 - for each $k$, if $A_k=\mathbb{N}$ then $A_{k+1}=\mathbb{N}$.

However, each of these steps takes proof - you don't get something for free. There's nothing spooky going on here.

Comment: To conclude $D = N$, from the fact that $D$ is inductive, i guess we do need Extensionality. Please correct me if i am wrong tho.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri It certainly is needed in my proof. Thanks.

Comment: Note that this is really just double induction phrased in terms of sets. You're proving "For all $k$, we have $\{x:\phi_k(x)\}$ is $\mathbb{N}$" - that's just "For all $k,m$ we have $\phi_k(m)$." Often we prove this by *simultaneous* induction on $k, m$, which isn't what you're describing, but there are also cases where you do "$k$ first, then $m$" - that is, by induction on $k$ you show by induction on $m$ that $\phi_k(m)$ always holds.

Comment: Just note that being an inductive set does not mean that you satisfy PA.

Comment: @AsafKaragila yea - I just googled and found https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_set - thanks